# why a particular variable is undefined only at one place in the complete component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, formik

```
import React from 'react';
import { Formik, Form } from "formik";
import { InputField } from "./formui/InputField";
import { applyGharwapasi } from "../../appollo/applyGharwapasi/applyGharwapasi";
import { useMutation } from '@apollo/client'


const Step3 = ({aadharId,ApplicantImgID}) => {

    const newId = ApplicantImgID;
    const [applyGharwapasihandle, { loading, error, data }] =
      useMutation(applyGharwapasi);
    console.log("The aadhar id is", aadharId,"The applicant image is",ApplicantImgID);
  
    const handleSubmit = async (values) => {
      console.log(values);
      try {
        applyGharwapasihandle({
          variables: {
            data: values,
          },
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
      console.log(data);
    };
  
    const formArray = [
      { label: "Name", placeholder: "Enter your name",type: "text",name: "Name",},
      {label: "Number",placeholder: "99xxxxx999",type: "text",name: "PhoneNumber",},
      {label: "Address",placeholder: "Address",type: "textarea",name: "Address",},
      {label: "Aadhar Number",placeholder: "22xx xxxx xxxx xxxx",type: "text",name: "AadharNumber",},
      {label: "Aadhar PDF",placeholder: "22xx xxxx xxxx xxxx",type: "text",name: "AadharPdf",},
      {label: "Image",placeholder: "22xx xxxx xxxx xxxx",type: "text",name: "ApplicantImage",},
    ];
    return (
      <div>
        {console.log("The applicant image is",ApplicantImgID)}
        <Formik
          initialValues={{
            Name: "",
            PhoneNumber: "",
            Address: "",
            AadharNumber: "",
            AadharPdf:`${aadharId}`,
            ApplicantImage:`${ApplicantImgID}`,
          }}
          onSubmit={(values) => {
            handleSubmit(values);
          }}
        >
          <Form>
            {formArray.map((item, index) => (
              <InputField key={index} label={item.label} placeholder={item.placeholder} type={item.type} name={item.name}/>
            ))}
            
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary col-md-12 my-3">
              Submit
            </button>
          </Form>
        </Formik>
      </div>
    );
  };

export default Step3
```

I am talking about the `ApplicantImgID` I am passing this prop from the parent component you can see i have console log the data which i have recived and it works fine
`console.log("The aadhar id is", aadharId,"The applicant image is",ApplicantImgID);`

I need to see the data here `ApplicantImage:`${ApplicantImgID}`` in formik initial value i cant figure out why even this is happening so frustated

Let me give more context which i have get during my diagnosis this `ApplicantImgId` is declared in a parent component `const [applicantImgId, setApplicantImgId] = useState();` if i give some initaial value here then while submitting form i get the initial value probably my parent component reset while submitting only for this `ApplicantImgID` i have other variable which is in step one `aadharId` it works fine

`https://github.com/sarangkkl/gharwapasi/tree/main/components/forms`

github file if you want to see the other component

Comment: Without the parent component's code, we can only guess what is happening.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski https://github.com/sarangkkl/gharwapasi/tree/main/components/forms here is the github file link where you find the component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code of your step 2 component.

```
fetch("http://localhost:1337/api/upload/", requestOptions)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(result =>{
        const output = JSON.parse(result);
        console.log(output[0].id);

        ApplicantImageId(output[0].id);
      })
      .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
    changeActive(2);
}
```

As you can see, you first run `changeActive` and then when the promise returns you set the `ApplicantImageId`. So step 3 is loaded before the data it requires hence `undefined`

Comment: Thanks Genious by thinking about the prop drilling I changed my strategy use context providor that also cause the same issue i fix it  by stop using formik now everything fiixed